# In JavaFX, Is it possible to enable a CheckBox when the TextField's value is not set to Zero

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

How can I enable my `CheckBox` when I type into the `TextField` a value other than zero?

By default, I've set my `CheckBox` to disable in the Scene Builder.

In my `MainController` class:

```
@FXML
private CheckBox cb1;

@FXML
private TextField txt1;

public void enableCB() {
    if (txt1.getText() == "0") {
        cb1.setDisable(true);
    } else {
        cb1.setDisable(false);
    }
}
```

In Scene Builder I've set the **"enableCb Method"** to the  **On Action** and **On Key Typed**, but still it did not provide the right condition and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a fairly simple, one-statement binding:

```
cb1.disableProperty().bind(
                txt1.textProperty().isEmpty()
                         .or(txt1.textProperty().isEqualTo("0")));
```

This will enable the `CheckBox` only if a value other than "0" has been entered into the `TextField`. So it will be disabled if the text is either empty or "0".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest writing a [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) for the [text property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty) of the `TextField`.

```java
txt1.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                        String oldValue,
                        String newValue) {
        if ("0".equals(newValue)) {
            cb1.setDisable(true);
        }
        else {
            cb1.setDisable(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Every time the text in the `TextField` is changed, the above code will execute, regardless of how the text is changed.

Also note that the way to compare different strings in Java is with method `equals` and not with the equals operator, i.e. `==`.